# Add a saving path with xhtml2pdf and download link?

Tags: python, html, django, pdf

I'm using xhtml2pdf in order to convert my form to PDF file.
By default, it saves this PDF to the same place than my manage.py file.

I'm asking How I can modify the saving path in order to send the PDF on my Desktop for example (with MacOSX)

This is my function :

```
def BirthCertificate_PDF(request, id) :

    birthcertificate = get_object_or_404(BirthCertificate, pk=id)

    data = {"birthcertificate" : birthcertificate}

    template = get_template('BC_raw.html')
    html  = template.render(Context(data))

    #filename = 'acte_de_naissance_' + str(BirthCertificate.lastname)
    filename = 'Acte_Naissance_' + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).lastname) + '_' + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).firstname) + '_' + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).birthday) + '.pdf'

    file = open(filename, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')

    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    if pdf :
        context = {"birthcertificate":birthcertificate}

        return render(request, 'BC_resume.html', context)
    file.close()

    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

I read this documentation : [xhtml2pdf doc](http://fwpn.org.pl/assets/event_attachments/asd.html) But I don't have any solution.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Then I have an other question (maybe I should create a new question ?). I put an HTML button which let to save the PDF. But I would like to have the following function :

I click on the button --> I get a window letting to open the PDF or save it

This is my html template which let to save the pdf :

```
<h2 align="center"> Votre formulaire a été validé </align> </h2>

{% block content %} 

L'enfant a été enregistré sous le numéro : {{ birthcertificate.id }} 

<h3> Récapitulatif des données enregistrées : </h3>

<li> Nom : {{birthcertificate.lastname}}</li>
<li> Prénom : {{birthcertificate.firstname}}</li>
<li> Sexe : {{birthcertificate.sex}}</li>
<li> Date de Naissance : {{birthcertificate.birthday}}</li>
<li> Ville de Naissance : {{birthcertificate.birthhour}}</li>
<li> Pays de Naissance : {{birthcertificate.birthcity}}</li>
<li> Nationalité : {{birthcertificate.birthcountry}}</li>
<li> Père : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1}}</li>
<li> Mère : {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2}}</li>

{% endblock %} 

<br></br>

<form method='POST' action="{% url "BChome" %}"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="submit" value="Retour gestion des actes de naissances" />
</form>

<form method='POST' action="{% url "PDF" birthcertificate.id %}"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="submit" value="Générer PDF acte de naissance" />
</form>


<form method='POST' action='/Identity/accueil'> {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="submit" value="Retour gestion des fiches identités" />
</form>
```

Thank you if you have advices about both questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you define where you want to save your file:

```
file = open(filename, "w+b")
pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')
```

Just change the filename to the destination where you want to save it, for the desktop:  `"/Users/userName/Desktop/" + filename`

So your code would look something like:

```
destination = "/Users/userName/Desktop/"
file = open(destination + filename, "w+b")
pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')
```

Ofcourse you can make the destination an argument of your function.